# Try to call other function inside function in the same class. Uncaught TypeError: this.saveToHist is not a function at HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a function in a class that call another function. The code is

```
    createElAdditive(){
      ...
      this.cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
        this.saveToHist();
        ...
      });
    }

    saveToHist() {
      this.historyNumber++;
      if (this.historyNumber < this.saveHistory.length) {
        this.saveHistory.length = this.historyNumber;
      }
      this.saveHistory.push(this.cvs.toDataURL());
    }
```

The two function is on the same class. How can I access other function in same class? In my case I want to call saveToHist function inside cvs event in createElAdditive function.

The complete code is on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/alien_gunung/pen/ZVEjLN?editors=1010) and you can try draw something on canvas to see error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` inside the `addEventListern()` block refers to something other than the instance of the object. You need to capture it from outside, then use it

```
 createElAdditive(){
      ...
      var that = this;          // captured here
      this.cvs.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
        that.saveToHist();      // used here
        ...
      });
    }
```